# Killing off Striped Maples

Tags: maple, native-plants

Striped Maple is a non-native plant in our area and is crowding out native plants.   It has started becoming a problem in my 10 acre forest area.

I am trying to figure out the least invasive way to kill it off.   I would prefer one that does not involve Round-Up or similar type herbicide.

Chopping it down and nipping off saplings in the Spring is not working.   They just grow back.  I tried an experiment last spring by both nipping off a sapling (about 3' high) and then covering the spot with a bucket to block it from getting light.   I just checked on it and found the bucket on its side and the sapling had re-grown.

I would really like a method that would cause no-harm to the native plants around the Striped Maples.

Comment: Cutting down a sapling three feet tall won't achieve anything. Trees don't die just because something eats them or tramples on them and breaks the main trunk. Repeatedly cutting saplings that are three *inches* tall back to the roots will work (eventually) , but you probably don't have the time and patience to do that.

Comment: I am not aware of striped maple (*Acer pensylvanicum*) being invasive anywhere. POWO does not list it introduced anywhere either, although their listing may be incomplete. It is also not widely planted as a nursery plant so it has not been on my radar for plants at risk of becoming invasive in new areas. I'd be curious as to where you are, because this is something I'd like to follow and look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet, other than completely uprooting all of the saplings, is an herbicide that you brush on to the cut stems/stumps. The best one of these, IMO, is triclopyr (if it's available in your area). So, you cut the stem at a convenient height, brush on the triclopyr, and then return whenever you want to to cut down the now-dead sapling. For larger trees, cut the tree down as normal, then brush triclopyr along the cambial layer (between the bark and the hardwood) the entire circumference of the tree. In the US, this herbicide is commonly sold as "Stump and Brush Killer".

Comment: If the OP "doesn't want to use round-up" (i.e. glyphosate), be aware that triclopyr is slightly *more* hazardous than glyphosate - though it is safe if used correctly.

Comment: I agree, which is why the brush-on method works best (I knew someone who sprayed it onto the cut stems and trunks, which is a terrible idea). The best thing about triclopyr is that it's effective against against woody plants without endangering any of the other plants in the area. IMO, glyphosate is used far too often for stupid reasons (example: my city sprays it indiscriminately in the city parks along things like fencelines so that they don't have to use a string trimmer. They also spray it on play areas. Yes, this is legal).

Comment: It never occurred to me to "paint" on the herbicide, which is why I accepted this answer.